# multiple variable data on Form Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

need your help on this one..
how to pass a multiple variable data on form using larvel...
i got some sample but there's an error

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: editeammember.post] [URI: editeammember/{idteam}/{idmember}]. (View: E:\wamp64\www\gplspring2017\resources\views\admin\editteammember.blade.php)
```

Here's my form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('editeammember.post', $member->gpl_team_id.'/'.$member->team_member_id) }}"></form>
```

here's my controller

```
public function editteammember(Request $request, $idteam, $idmember)
    {
        $teams = DB::table('gpl_team')->where('gpl_team_id', $idteam)->get(); 

        $count = count($teams);

        if(!$count)
        {
            return redirect('404');
        }
        else
        {
            $member_image = $request->input('member_image');
            $member_summoner = $request->input('member_summoner');
            $member_name = $request->input('member_name');
            $member_role = $request->input('member_role');
            $updated_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $this->validate(request(), [
                'member_image' => 'required|max:255',
                'member_summoner' => 'required|max:255',
                'member_name' => 'required|max:255',
                'member_role' => 'in:Top Lane, Jungle, Mid Lane, AD Carry, Support, Substitute',
                ]
            );   

            DB::table('team_member')->where('team_member_id', $idmember)->where('gpl_team_id', $idteam)->update([
                ['member_pic' => $member_image, 'member_summoner' => $member_summoner, 'member_name' => $member_name, 'member_role' => $member_role, 'updated_at' => $updated_at, ]
            ]);

            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Member is successfully Updated!');
        }
    }
```

hope you can help me... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass your params as an array :

```
{{ route('editeammember.post', [$member->gpl_team_id, $member->team_member_id]) }}
```

for more reference : [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route)